# Postgresql redundancy for read-only queries with refresh on demand

Tags: postgresql, replication

I was wondering if there are any postgresql tools which would facilitate replication to read-only server on demand. Here is problem description:

- Every data changing process is running as multiple transactions (processes are complex - for example, load data, run calculation, run more data, etc.). Until process is finished, I consider database to be *inconsistent* for reporting.
- Reports should use only *consistent* data, but shouldn't wait for the data changing process to complete - they should use old (*consistent*) data.

Ideally, reports should run on a *consistent* snapshot of the database.
The idea to solve this problem is as follows:

- have two servers - master and slave. Initially both having exactly same data.
- all data-changing processes will run on master
- all reporting tasks will run on slave
- once data-changing process is completed, refresh of slave is triggered. Trigger would be for example: run some command, create a file on filesystem, etc. Reading partially refreshed slave is not permited.

  - this can't take too long - should be proportional to size of changes on master

Slave will not be used for fail over, this is not the purpose.

Is there any good solution to this problem? Or maybe it can be solved in a different way?

Comment: Why don't you make your "data changing process" to run a single transaction that reflects your business requirements? That's what transactions are for: don't make anything visible until the data is consistent

Comment: One solution I can think of: create FDW tables for each source table, create materialized views based on the FDW tables and refresh the MVIEWS once you know your database is in a consistent state.

Comment: Running everything on one transaction is not really an option. The process involves multiple threads, processes, binaries. Mat. views could be an option potentially, if they could refresh only new data, not the whole view - as far as I know, postgresql doesn't support it (?). It will take too much time.

Comment: `Until process is finished, I consider database to be inconsistent for reporting.` So I assume that there is a moment that no processes are running, right? Otherwise the database would be "inconsistent" all the time. So I guess that the simplest solution would be to ensure that during time interval X the database is "consistent" (i.e. no processing is running), make a snapshot and upload it onto slave.

Comment: @freakish: yes, there are processes which run a few times a day and last between 0.01s to 10 minutes (depends on the process). By snapshot you mean creating a full backup? It's way too slow. If there was some option to ship only transaction log *on demand*, would be great.

Comment: `The process involves multiple threads, processes, binaries.` I hope these preocesses don't interfere. (use/update the same tables, etc. -> second task must be started after first has finished)

Comment: No worries, processes are fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a nice solution to this. Postgres >= 9.2 has possibility to export a snapshot id of current transaction. Every transaction which uses the same snapshot id, will see the same data at the beginning.

In my case, I can create a "dummy" transaction and export its snapshot it. Dummy transaction will not do anything, it will start when a process is starting and finish when it's finished. All the reports will use this snapshot id to report data which was visible at the time, when dummy transaction was created.

More about snapshots here: https://www.willglynn.com/2013/10/25/postgresql-snapshot-export/